# D3.js Flip Graph Horizontally

Tags: javascript, canvas, d3.js

I'm working on a rendering a tree structure very similar to D3's [Cluster Dendogram Example](http://bl.ocks.org/4063570).

I need to flip the graph horizontally so the parent nodes are on the right and the children are on the left.  The text on the labels cannot be flipped.  Which D3 methods are responsible for this?

Code from the example:

```
var width = 960,
height = 2200;

var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
    .size([height, width - 160]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");

d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
    var nodes = cluster.nodes(root),
        links = cluster.links(nodes);

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(links)
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", diagonal);

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 4.5);

    node.append("text")
        .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.children ? -8 : 8; })
        .attr("dy", 3)
        .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children ? "end" : "start"; })
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
});
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930401/smooth-transitioning-between-tree-cluster-radial-tree-and-radial-cluster-layo for more possibilities on adjusting a hierarchical layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the coordinates come from the cluster layout. You can either modify the layout or in the code subtracting `.x` from the width of the layout, i.e. `width - 160`. You might also want to adjust the `text-anchor` attribute value.

Comment: Actually, the coordinates are not encoded in the JSON.  You can view the JSON here: http://bl.ocks.org/d/4063570/flare.json

Comment: Ah, you're right of course. The coordinates come from the layout. I've edited the answer -- the rest is still valid though.