# How to display JSON data in form of different tree-like layouts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js, tree

Hi Guys i have managed to generate JSON data from my database in order to show Organization Structure in my compnay. Below is a snapshot of the JSON file format. Note the actual json file is about 4 MB in size which means a lot of data and i have validated and it works fine too. I used the below d3 framework.

> http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

However, I also want to show the same data to user in different layout for example like a Tree Structure other than the one mentioned above. Is there any other framework I can use to display my JSON file in Tree like structure or any?

OrgChart.json

```
{
   "name":"xyz",
   "children":[
      {
         "name":"first",
         "children":[
            {
               "name":"Level 1",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "name":"Name 1",
                     "amount":3938
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"Name 2",
                     "amount":3812
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },

    {
         "name":"second",
         "children":[
            {
               "name":"Level 2",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "name":"Name 1",
                     "amount":3938
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"Name 2",
                     "amount":3812
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript

Comment: Most if not all the implementations of the [Hierarchy Layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Hierarchy-Layout) can be fed this data structure. For some closely related layouts, you can even add some fun [transitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930401/smooth-transitioning-between-tree-cluster-radial-tree-and-radial-cluster-layo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like d3 js especially to display data driven docs. More info on : http://d3js.org/